# IBM Business Process Manager integratin with lotus notes

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, business-process-management

I am working on the integration of Lotus Notes with IBM BPM with the help of java. I have done research on this I found some ways:
1. Connect the lotus notes using Doming.
2. Connect the lotus notes using webservices.
I did not found any solution which can address the issue of connecting the IBM BPM with lotus notes.
Suggest me some ways how IBM BPM can be connected with Lotus notes with java program.

Comment: Please define your objective more clearly. Give us an exact scenario of some data, some actions, and how you want those actions to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to expose a BPM application in a Lotus Notes app, or are you just trying to get tasks to be sent to users mail boxes in Notes, are you wanting to expose BPM portal functions in a LN database....?

I'm not very familiar with Lotus Notes apps, but I would guess that you might want to look into the BPM REST API.  If Lotus Notes has a way to interface with a REST API this might do what you want.  Here is a link to the IBM BPM 8.5 REST API documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wbpm.bpc.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcdev_restapis.html